# Why does my Vue app get an error when I try to pay on a mobile device with Google Pay: Blocked a frame with origin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-pay

Implementation of payment via Google Pay in Chrome on the desktop works fine, and when you try to pay via a smartphone, an error pops up (in the case of a smartphone, an additional modal window appears with a choice of a card):

```
vue.esm.js?a026:152 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at hasOwnProperty ()
at hasOwn (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.es...)
at observe (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.es...)
at Oc.reactiveSetter [as Ya] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.es...)
at Oc.show (https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:146:528)
at https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:223:374
hasOwn @ vue.esm.js?a026:152
observe @ vue.esm.js?a026:988
reactiveSetter @ vue.esm.js?a026:1063
Oc.show @ pay.js:146
(anonymous) @ pay.js:223
Promise.then (async)
W.V @ pay.js:223
k.V @ pay.js:241
(anonymous) @ pay.js:255
k.V @ pay.js:255
onGooglePaymentButtonClicked @ app.vue?1919:483
```

At the same time, if you try the example of implementing Google Pay payment in pure JS, then everything works out fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the code sample you're using?

I've got a sample Vue application on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/google-pay-vue

Note that you'll need to tap the **Open in new window** link for the demo to work correctly.

As an FYI, this code sample uses the Google Pay button web component: https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button/tree/main/src/button-element#example-usage-vue-website

Comment: pay.js:197 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': [object Object] could not be cloned.
    at V (https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:197:13)
    at Vd (https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:196:300)
    at Yd.qa (https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:208:252)
    at U.qa (https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:199:116)
    at U.nc (https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:198:301)

Comment: You're getting the error above when testing the StackBlitz example? What are the details of your smartphone/browser? A user agent string might be helpful.

Comment: Desktop, Chrome 89.0.4389.90